# LinkedIn-Api This resource is no longer available under v1 APIs with nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, linkedin-api

errorCode: 0,
  message: 'This resource is no longer available under v1 APIs',
  requestId: 'P7A442E64SX4',
  status: 410,
  timestamp: 1574400301580

Comment: I think you should linkedin V2 API. https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/concepts

Comment: Please tell us which npm package you have installed for linkedin API.

Comment: i am using node-linkedin  npm package